# How to edit content structure xml in liferay IDE?

Tags: xml, liferay, liferay-ide

I'm a newby in liferay development. I'd like to use Liferay IDE for editing the xml code of a content structure. I know it can be done by web interface but, due the complexity of the content structure, I'd prefer the text editor way.

I've downloaded the content structure in a lar file and have the liferay IDE working on my computer.

**How I import the lar file so I can work on it?**

Thanks

Comment: If it is a matter of couple of contents,you can rather copy the contents of structure and paste it in editor for better formatting or unzip the lar to check for the structure file and edit in IDE.There is no direct method to open a lar in any of the IDEs

Comment: Thanks @ShivamAggarwal! You solved my question! I've pasted the code in the editor view.

Comment: I that solves your issue,I will rather add my comment as an answer to be helpful & relevant to others as well

Answer (score 0):

If it is a matter of couple of contents,you can rather

1. Copy the contents of structure and paste it in editor for better formatting ,or
2. Unzip the lar to check for the structure file and edit in IDE.

There is no direct method to open a lar in any of the IDEs